# Using Texlive installed in Windows for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, latex

I have both Win7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I use Texlive 2012 with Texmaker in Win7. Is it possible to use it (Texlive) in Ubuntu so I won't have to download 2Gb again! I hope it was clear.

(I'm newbie in Linux.)

Comment: If it's possible, I don't believe it is an easy task. You can install `texlive` and `cm-super` which are 534 MB and install other needed stuff on the go. You can also install `texlive-base` (without `cm-super`) which would amount to 129 MB and work with that (if possible) while the other stuff is downloaded. These packages are available in the Software Center or via `apt-get`.

Comment: @edwin Yeah. You're right. You know what! nothing's easy in Linux as far as I know! Thanks for comment anyway. Texlive-base would do but I'll need the full one at last if I wanna live!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the Texlive executable in [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), which lets you run Windows executables in Ubuntu. In order to install it you can run this command in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install wine`.

However, I would recommend you to install it again in Ubuntu because you get the updates along with the rest of the system updates. In this case you need to use this command in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install texlive-base`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I've used Wine before. It's useful for people like me! However, I think I have to download the full Texlive. There's no way to use that installed in Windows.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to use the one installed in Windows. Firstly mount the Windows partition with the following commands: Create the directory: 'sudo mkdir /media/win' then check, what the id of the windows partition is (something like “/dev/sda+number”, you can find it by launching the gnome disk utility with the command: 'gnome-disks'). At next , use the  id of the windows partition instead of the X: 'sudo mount -t ntfs -o uid=1000,umask=0022 /dev/X /media/win'. Finally go to the windows directory with 'cd /media/win' and start the latex exe with wine: 'wine "./WINDOWS_LATEX_PATH"'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. well, I think this may work. I mean it must.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above by [user3289604](https://askubuntu.com/users/246419/user3289604):

1. First install `sudo apt-get install wine`.
2. Then install `sudo apt-get install texlive-base`.

This will help to run windows `.exe` files directly without using the `wine` command explicitly as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyl1f.png).
If problem exists follow steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230553/how-to-associate-exe-files-with-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/48773/how-to-run-an-exe-from-linux-command-prompt).

To make this work with [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/):

1. Go to Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Commands.
2. There you will find Commands like LateX, PdfLaTeX etc.
3. Add PATH to orginal file location in windows directory as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw4hD.png).
4. Eg: LaTeX: `/media/sdebnath/OS/texlive/2023/bin/windows/latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.
5. Do this for all commands.
6. Compile and check if working.