# How to associate exe files with Wine on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nautilus, wine

Installed Wine from terminal `$ sudo apt install wine`. Right clicking on exe file in Files suggests opening it with "Archive Manager". Wine is not present in "Open With Other Application" -> "View All Applications" list either.
How do I associate exe files with Wine, so they could be opened from Files just by double clicking? I'm trying to set up OS for less experienced user.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install `wine-binfmt`.

Also copy `wine.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications` or to `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. You will find `wine.desktop` in `/usr/share/doc/wine/examples/wine.desktop`.

```
cp /usr/share/doc/wine/examples/wine.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/
```

or

```
cp /usr/share/doc/wine/examples/wine.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Comment: This actually lets me run exe files from terminal like Linux binaries, when they have correct execute permissions. I am searching for a way to have "Open With Wine" association for exe files in Files (Nautilus) file manager.

Comment: Ok try `cp /usr/share/doc/wine/examples/wine.desktop $HOME/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: Great, this one works. Could you post it as answer, so I could properly mark it as accepted?

Comment: There is no wine.desktop anywhere on my notebook - -?

Comment: It is part of the standard wine installation as in `sudo apt install wine`. It will be found in `/usr/share/doc/wine/examples/`